# Transformation on Squeeze Operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, squeezed-states

Yesterday, my professor briefly glossed over the following computation without details, and I haven't been able to figure it out for myself.

How would I compute $$(\cosh (q) \hat{a} + \sinh (q) \hat{a}^{\dagger})\exp(-\frac{q}{2}[(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2 - \hat{a}^{2}]|0⟩$$ where $q \in \mathbf{R}$, and $|0⟩$ is the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator?

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator  where they use the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff Formula

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is not simple. The usual approach requires that you first represent the squeezing operator in normal order, which requires that you separate the squeezing operator into three exponentiated operators with $(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2$, $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$, and $\hat{a}^2$. Then you need to separate the middle one further into normal ordered products. It is a very long and tedious calculation.

A simpler approach is to use Wigner functions. Since both the squeezing operation and the displacement operation are unitary operations, they can be represented as transformations of the argument of the vacuum state's Wigner function, as a Bogoliubov transformation and a displacement, respectively. Then you can use a Weyl transformation to convert the resulting Wigner function back to a density operator. (Or you can just leave it as a Wigner function.)